# kummer extension on SAGE

Tags: extension-field, sagemath, kummer-theory

I want to calculate the relative discriminant of field extensions of this kind:
$$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)(\sqrt[5]{a})$$
Where $a \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$. So I use SAGE and make this calculations:

```
K.<b>=CyclotomicField(5);    //my field base
alpha=1+3*b^2;               //an element of my field base
f=(1+3*b^2).minpoly();       //its minimal polynomial
f.is_irreducible()           //is it irreducible?
R.<a>=K.extension(f)         //the field extension of my field base
R.relative_discriminant()    //the calculation of the relative discriminant
```

But when I execute it, appears this error

```
defining polynomial (x^4 - x^3 + 6*x^2 + 14*x + 61) must be irreducible
```

But it is irreducible, what am I doing wrong? Or how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is the best place to ask sage questions, but the problem is here that the minimal polynomial $f$ of $\alpha$ is of course not irreducible over $K$. Probably you meant to do the following:

```
K.<b>=CyclotomicField(5)
alpha=1+3*b^2
P.<x>=K[]
R.<a>=K.extension(x^5-alpha)
R.relative_discriminant()
```

which gives:

```
Fractional ideal (-203125*b^3 - 121875*b^2 - 3125*b - 50000)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! This worked perfectly. I wanna calculate relative discriminants of those extensions when they are galois over Q, is difficult to find when they are galois over Q, but is also nice.